# Add <img> tag to BlueImp gallery title

Tags: javascript, html, blueimp

I'm trying to add an  tag to the title of each video (this gallery holds Youtube videos instead of images) on a BlueImp gallery like so:

```
galleryVideos.push({
                    title: " <img src='link.jpg'>",
                    href: 'http://link.com',
                    type: 'text/html'
                  })
```

But when it gets rendered the text on the screen is `<img src='link.jpg'>` (it renders the text instead of the image), and when I inspect the tag looks like:

```
<h3 class="title"> &lt;img src='link.jpg'&gt;</h3>
```

If I manually edit the HTML code through the developer tools editor, and substitute the `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `<` and `>` anchor symbols the image renders correctly.

I have tried escaping the characters but no luck.

Greetings
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the title value is automatically escaped to avoid script injection attack.

By looking the [BlueImp doc](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md#api), you need to do something like this :

```
galleryVideos.push({
                title: '',
                href: 'http://link.com',
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                thumbnail: 'link.jpg'
              })
```

Comment: I didn't mention a detail that might be relevant, this gallery holds Youtube videos instead of images.

If I change the type from `'text/html'` to `'image/jpeg'`, the video doesn't render. 

The thumbnail property has no effect either